# Erro de compilação PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Alguém saberia me dizer se existe algum erro na query abaixo:

```
select name, cast(Extract(day from payday) as int) as 'day' from loan;
```

Não consigo encontrar o motivo de apresentar erro de compilação no URI.

Comment: Troque 'day' por "day". O primeiro é uma string e o segundo um identificador delimitado (ou quoted identifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei que o problema estaria no *cast*; fui criar [este fiddle](https://rextester.com/NHY30010) e percebi que a mensagem de erro (*42601: syntax error at or near "'day'"*) está relacionada ao *alias*, não ao `extract`.

Removendo as aspas, o problema está resolvido:

```
select name, cast(Extract(day from payday) as int) as day from loan;
```

Comment: Você pode nomear com aspas duplas, e não com aspas simples (apóstrofo): "Day".